# Access properties of object that is an array in another object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have two classes: CarRentComp and Cars.

CarRentComp has an array of cars. I need to insert to DB the CarRentComp and one Car (so the array is length 1 for now).

My problem is that I can't actually access the Cars properties.

I come from a Java/C# background so I'm trying to translate some of what I did to Python.

The two files:

```
class Car():
__plate=""

def set_plate(self, pPlate):
    self.__plate=pPlate

def get_plate(self):
    return self.__plate

def __init__(self,pPlate):
    self.set_plate(pPlate)

from car import Car
class CarRentComp():
__name=""
__cars=[Car("")]

def set_name(self, pName):
    self.__name=pName
def get_name(self):
    return self.__name

def set_cars(self, pCars):
    self.__name=pCars

def get_cars(self):
    return self.__cars

def __init__(self,pName, pCars):
    self.set_name(pName)
    self.set_cars(pCars)

from carrentcomp import CarRentComp
class OpsCarRentComp():

    def insert_carrentcomp(self, carrentcomp = CarRentComp):
        name = carrentcomp.get_name()
        vehicles = carrentcomp.get_cars()

        car1 = vehicles[0]

        plate = car1..get_plate()
```

I'm calling insert_carrentcomp from another file and adding the CarRentComp and its car to the array:

```
car1 = Car("AAA2345")

add_car_rent_comp= CarRentComp("Deluxe Cars", [car1])

OpsCarRentComp.insert_carrentcomp(OpsCarRentComp, add_car_rent_comp)
```

I can't access the cars properties, like its plate from the class OpsCarRentComp.

plate = car1..get_plate() --when I compare it to CarRentComp, it is one of the arguments that my method takes. I'm kind of struggling with Python and its simpler way to do things.

Comment: please edit your question and fix the indentation. As you know, in Python, it is not a "nice to have"  -it the very structure of your code. Use the `{}` button to format code instead of trying to rely on the existing indentation to provide the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `insert_carrentcomp` method is not using self, you might want to make it `@staticmethod`.

Try something like:

```
class OpsCarRentComp:
    @staticmethod
    def insert_carrentcomp(carrentcomp: CarRentComp):
        name = carrentcomp.get_name()
        vehicles = carrentcomp.get_cars()

        car1 = vehicles[0]

        plate = car1.get_plate()

car1 = Car("AAA2345")

add_car_rent_comp= CarRentComp("Deluxe Cars", [car1])

OpsCarRentComp.insert_carrentcomp(add_car_rent_comp)
```